# SASL/SCRAM works with confluentinc images, but fails with wurstmeister

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, sasl-scram

I have SASL/SCRAM config working with confluentinc kafka/zookeeper:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
# Based on: https://github.com/iwpnd/tile38-kafka-sasl
version: "2"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.0.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://zookeeper:2181
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 3
      KAFKA_OPTS: "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/secrets/sasl/zookeeper_jaas.conf \
          -Dzookeeper.authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider \
          -Dzookeeper.authProvider.2=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestAuthenticationProvider \
          -Dquorum.auth.enableSasl=true \
          -Dquorum.auth.learnerRequireSasl=true \
          -Dquorum.auth.serverRequireSasl=true \
          -Dquorum.auth.learner.saslLoginContext=QuorumLearner \
          -Dquorum.auth.server.saslLoginContext=QuorumServer \
          -Dquorum.cnxn.threads.size=20 \
          -DrequireClientAuthScheme=sasl"
    volumes:
      - ./secrets:/etc/kafka/secrets/sasl

  zookeeper-add-kafka-users:
      image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.0.1
      container_name: "zookeeper-add-kafka-users"
      depends_on:
        - zookeeper
      command: "bash -c 'echo Waiting for Zookeeper to be ready... && \
                          cub zk-ready zookeeper:2181 120 && \
                          kafka-configs --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --alter --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-512=[iterations=4096,password=password]' --entity-type users --entity-name admin && \
                          kafka-configs --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --alter --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-512=[iterations=4096,password=password]' --entity-type users --entity-name client '"
      environment:
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: ignored
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: ignored
        KAFKA_OPTS: -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/secrets/sasl/kafka_server_jaas.conf
      volumes:
        - ./secrets:/etc/kafka/secrets/sasl

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.0.1
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9091:9091"
      - "9101:9101"
      - "9092:9092"
    expose:
      - "29090"
    environment:
      KAFKA_OPTS: "-Dzookeeper.sasl.client=true -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/secrets/sasl/kafka_server_jaas.conf"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT,SASL_PLAINHOST:SASL_PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:29090,OUTSIDE://:9092,SASL_PLAINHOST://:9091
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://broker:29090,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092,SASL_PLAINHOST://broker:9091
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCAL: SASL_PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS: SCRAM-SHA-512
      KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: PLAINTEXT
    volumes:
      - ./secrets:/etc/kafka/secrets/sasl
```

**sercrets/kafka_server_jaas.conf**

```
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
    username="admin"
    password="password"
    user_admin="password"
    user_client="password";
};

Client {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username="admin"
    password="password";
};

KafkaClient {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
    username="client"
    password="password";
};
```

**sercerts/zk_server_jaas.conf**

```
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="admin-secret"
  user_admin="admin-secret";
};
```

**sercrets/zookeeper_jaas.conf zk_server_jaas.conf**

```
Server {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    user_admin="password";
};
QuorumServer {
       org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
       user_admin="password";
};
 
QuorumLearner {
       org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
       username="admin"
       password="password";
};
```

Above config works as I expected with `confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.0.1` image, but when I change images to `wurstmeister/zookeeper` and `wurstmeister/kafka:2.13-2.7.1` I get below errors:

```
[36mbroker                       |[0m [Configuring] 'security.inter.broker.protocal' in '/opt/kafka/config/server.properties'
[36mbroker                       |[0m [Configuring] 'jmx.port' in '/opt/kafka/config/server.properties'
[36mbroker                       |[0m [Configuring] 'advertised.listeners' in '/opt/kafka/config/server.properties'
[36mbroker                       |[0m [Configuring] 'port' in '/opt/kafka/config/server.properties'
[36mbroker                       |[0m [Configuring] 'inter.broker.listener.name' in '/opt/kafka/config/server.properties'
[36mbroker                       |[0m Excluding KAFKA_OPTS from broker config
[36mbroker                       |[0m Excluding KAFKA_HOME from broker config
[36mbroker                       |[0m [Configuring] 'log.dirs' in '/opt/kafka/config/server.properties'
[36mbroker                       |[0m [Configuring] 'listeners' in '/opt/kafka/config/server.properties'
[36mbroker                       |[0m Excluding KAFKA_VERSION from broker config
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m Using config: /opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,364 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@136] - Reading configuration from: /opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,370 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@78] - autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,370 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@79] - autopurge.purgeInterval set to 1
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,371 [myid:] - WARN  [main:QuorumPeerMain@116] - Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,376 [myid:] - INFO  [PurgeTask:DatadirCleanupManager$PurgeTask@138] - Purge task started.
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,396 [myid:] - INFO  [PurgeTask:DatadirCleanupManager$PurgeTask@144] - Purge task completed.
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,396 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@136] - Reading configuration from: /opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,397 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@98] - Starting server
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,409 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.13-2d71af4dbe22557fda74f9a9b4309b15a7487f03, built on 06/29/2018 04:05 GMT
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,409 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:host.name=zookeeper
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,409 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.version=1.7.0_65
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,410 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,410 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,410 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.class.path=/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../build/classes:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../lib/netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../lib/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../zookeeper-3.4.13.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13/bin/../conf:
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,410 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,410 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,413 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,413 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.name=Linux
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,414 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.arch=amd64
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,414 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.version=5.11.0-40-generic
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,414 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.name=root
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,414 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.home=/root
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,415 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.dir=/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,422 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@836] - tickTime set to 2000
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,425 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@845] - minSessionTimeout set to -1
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,426 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@854] - maxSessionTimeout set to -1
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,443 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ServerCnxnFactory@117] - Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory as server connection factory
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:55,453 [myid:] - INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@89] - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
[32mzookeeper-add-kafka-users    |[0m Waiting for Zookeeper to be ready...
[32mzookeeper-add-kafka-users    |[0m bash: line 1: cub: command not found
[36mbroker                       |[0m [Configuring] 'zookeeper.connect' in '/opt/kafka/config/server.properties'
[36mbroker                       |[0m [Configuring] 'sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol' in '/opt/kafka/config/server.properties'
[36mbroker                       |[0m [Configuring] 'offsets.topic.replication.factor' in '/opt/kafka/config/server.properties'
[36mbroker                       |[0m [Configuring] 'listener.security.protocol.map' in '/opt/kafka/config/server.properties'
[36mbroker                       |[0m [Configuring] 'jmx.hostname' in '/opt/kafka/config/server.properties'
[36mbroker                       |[0m [Configuring] 'sasl.enabled.mechanisms' in '/opt/kafka/config/server.properties'
[36mbroker                       |[0m [Configuring] 'broker.id' in '/opt/kafka/config/server.properties'
[32mzookeeper-add-kafka-users exited with code 127
[0m[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:58,599] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,195] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,343] INFO Registered signal handlers for TERM, INT, HUP (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,357] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,360] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on zookeeper:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,398] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Initializing a new session to zookeeper:2181. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,429] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.5.9-83df9301aa5c2a5d284a9940177808c01bc35cef, built on 01/06/2021 20:03 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,434] INFO Client environment:host.name=broker (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,435] INFO Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_292 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,435] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=Azul Systems, Inc. (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,435] INFO Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/zulu8-ca/jre (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,435] INFO Client environment:java.class.path=/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/activation-1.1.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-cli-1.4.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-api-2.7.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-basic-auth-extension-2.7.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-file-2.7.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-json-2.7.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-2.7.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-client-2.7.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-2.7.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-transforms-2.7.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.6.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.6.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.6.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.10.5.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.10.5.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.10.5.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.10.5.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.5.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.10.5.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.10.5.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.10.5.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-paranamer-2.10.5.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-scala_2.13-2.10.5.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.inject-2.6.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javassist-3.25.0-GA.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javassist-3.26.0-GA.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-client-2.31.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-common-2.31.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-2.31.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.31.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-hk2-2.31.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-media-jaxb-2.31.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-server-2.31.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-client-9.4.38.v20210224.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-continuation-9.4.38.v20210224.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-http-9.4.38.v20210224.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-io-9.4.38.v20210224.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-security-9.4.38.v20210224.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-server-9.4.38.v20210224.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet-9.4.38.v20210224.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets-9.4.38.v20210224.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-util-9.4.38.v20210224.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-util-ajax-9.4.38.v20210224.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-log4j-appender-2.7.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-raft-2.7.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-2.7.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-examples-2.7.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-scala_2.13-2.7.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-test-utils-2.7.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-tools-2.7.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.13-2.7.1-sources.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.13-2.7.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/lz4-java-1.7.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/maven-artifact-3.6.3.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-buffer-4.1.59.Final.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-codec-4.1.59.Final.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-common-4.1.59.Final.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-handler-4.1.59.Final.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-resolver-4.1.59.Final.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-4.1.59.Final.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.59.Final.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.59.Final.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.3.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/paranamer-2.8.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/reflections-0.9.12.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/rocksdbjni-5.18.4.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-collection-compat_2.13-2.2.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-java8-compat_2.13-0.9.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-library-2.13.3.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-logging_2.13-3.9.2.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-reflect-2.13.3.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/snappy-java-1.1.7.7.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.5.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/zookeeper-jute-3.5.9.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/zstd-jni-1.4.5-6.jar (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,437] INFO Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/zulu8-ca/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/zulu8-ca/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/zulu8-ca/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,437] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,440] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,441] INFO Client environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,441] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,441] INFO Client environment:os.version=5.11.0-40-generic (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,442] INFO Client environment:user.name=root (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,442] INFO Client environment:user.home=/root (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,442] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/ (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,443] INFO Client environment:os.memory.free=1014MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,443] INFO Client environment:os.memory.max=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,443] INFO Client environment:os.memory.total=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,447] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=zookeeper:2181 sessionTimeout=18000 watcher=kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$ZooKeeperClientWatcher$@4cc451f2 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,459] INFO jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,469] INFO zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled= (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,481] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,580] INFO Client successfully logged in. (org.apache.zookeeper.Login)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,582] INFO Client will use DIGEST-MD5 as SASL mechanism. (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,595] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper/172.20.0.2:2181. Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:59,605 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@215] - Accepted socket connection from /172.20.0.3:57480
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,609] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /172.20.0.3:57480, server: zookeeper/172.20.0.2:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:59,621 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@949] - Client attempting to establish new session at /172.20.0.3:57480
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:59,624 [myid:] - INFO  [SyncThread:0:FileTxnLog@213] - Creating new log file: log.1
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,642] INFO Session establishment complete on server zookeeper/172.20.0.2:2181, sessionid = 0x100474bc7f70000, negotiated timeout = 18000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:59,642 [myid:] - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@694] - Established session 0x100474bc7f70000 with negotiated timeout 18000 for client /172.20.0.3:57480
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,646] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:59,657 [myid:] - ERROR [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@1063] - cnxn.saslServer is null: cnxn object did not initialize its saslServer properly.
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,660] ERROR SASL authentication failed using login context 'Client' with exception: {} (org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient)
[36mbroker                       |[0m javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Error in authenticating with a Zookeeper Quorum member: the quorum member's saslToken is null.
[36mbroker                       |[0m     at org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient.createSaslToken(ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:312)
[36mbroker                       |[0m     at org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient.respondToServer(ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:275)
[36mbroker                       |[0m     at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.readResponse(ClientCnxn.java:882)
[36mbroker                       |[0m     at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:103)
[36mbroker                       |[0m     at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:365)
[36mbroker                       |[0m     at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1223)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,669] ERROR [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Auth failed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,672] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x100474bc7f70000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:59,794 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@376] - Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x100474bc7f70000, likely client has closed socket
[33mzookeeper                    |[0m 2021-12-04 13:17:59,795 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1056] - Closed socket connection for client /172.20.0.3:57480 which had sessionid 0x100474bc7f70000
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,823] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[36mbroker                       |[0m org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$AuthFailedException: KeeperErrorCode = AuthFailed for /consumers
[36mbroker                       |[0m     at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:130)
[36mbroker                       |[0m     at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)
[36mbroker                       |[0m     at kafka.zookeeper.AsyncResponse.maybeThrow(ZooKeeperClient.scala:564)
[36mbroker                       |[0m     at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.createRecursive(KafkaZkClient.scala:1662)
[36mbroker                       |[0m     at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.makeSurePersistentPathExists(KafkaZkClient.scala:1560)
[36mbroker                       |[0m     at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.$anonfun$createTopLevelPaths$1(KafkaZkClient.scala:1552)
[36mbroker                       |[0m     at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.$anonfun$createTopLevelPaths$1$adapted(KafkaZkClient.scala:1552)
[36mbroker                       |[0m     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:333)
[36mbroker                       |[0m     at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.createTopLevelPaths(KafkaZkClient.scala:1552)
[36mbroker                       |[0m     at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:467)
[36mbroker                       |[0m     at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:233)
[36mbroker                       |[0m     at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
[36mbroker                       |[0m     at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
[36mbroker                       |[0m     at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,825] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,836] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,845] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,849] INFO App info kafka.server for -1 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,854] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,855] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[36mbroker                       |[0m [2021-12-04 13:17:59,859] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[36mbroker exited with code 1
[0m
```

**Any tips how to get it work with wurstmeister images?**

Comment: Why change the image? We typically inject configuration into containers via environment variables. However, using environment variables and injection process are different for each container developer. So, it may not work if just change the images.

Comment: Agreed. It's the same Apache Kafka at the end of the day. Confluent actually maintains their images at an enterprise level, not a community project. If you simply want a smaller, maintained image, use Bitnami